# Not getting any results in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

For some reason, every time I run exec

```
communications_getCode @telCode='MX'
```

I get empty results. I know I am missing something because if I run

```
Select * from tbl_telCode where code = 'MX'
```

I get results (1 to be precise). But if I try it with the procedure, I get blank results

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.communications_getCode
    @telcode varchar
AS
    SELECT 
        id, code, detail
    FROM 
        tbl_telCode
    WHERE
        [code] = @telcode;
```

I do not know what am I missing.

Comment: Never use straight `varchar`, so first thing, change `@telcode varchar` to `@telcode varchar(x)` where `x` is the largest number of chars that column can contain. The default length is 1, so you will end up passing in 'M' only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `varchar` in the declaration defaults to `varchar(1)`.  When you pass a longer string, it gets truncated to one character.

In SQL Server, *always* user a length with string definitions:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.communications_getCode (
    @telcode varchar(255)
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT id, code, detail
    FROM tbl_telCode
    WHERE [code] = @telcode;
END;
```

Note that the body of the stored procedure is wrapped in a `BEGIN`/`END`. I find this to be a useful practice.

Also, there is no reason to define a stored procedure for this.  In my opinion, this would be better defined as a function.

Comment: Did not know it takes varchar(1) by default. TYVM that worked!

Comment: @HenryB . . . The default varies by context; in other situations it is not "1".  I wish SQL Server either generated a syntax error when using the types without a length or introduced a `string` type of some sort that doesn't require a length.